# How to cleanup Google AdSense errors in React 18 with new useEffect hook automatic remounting behaviour?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, adsense, code-cleanup

I am building a next.js website and intend to include Google AdSense at some point in the future. After following some examples and implementing the scripts as per a Next project I am hitting a wall with this error:

> "adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them."

My component looks like this:

```tsx
const GoogleAdSenseContainer = ({
  client = AdSense_ID,
  slot,
  className,
  responsive = true,
  displayAdSize = displayAdSizes.responsive,
  adUnitKey,
}: Props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const loadAds = () => {
    try {
      window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || [];
      window.adsbygoogle.push({});
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(' AdSense Error', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    loadAds();
  }, [adUnitKey, router]);

  return (
    <div
      className={cx(styles.adSenseContainer, className)}
      style={{ overflow: 'hidden' }}
      key={adUnitKey}
    >
      <span className={styles.adLabel}>Advertisement</span>
      <ins
        className='adsbygoogle'
        style={displayAdSize}
        data-ad-client={client}
        data-ad-slot={slot}
        data-ad-format={responsive && 'auto'}
        data-full-width-responsive={responsive}
      ></ins>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This pretty much works as intended, *however*, because of the new remounting behaviour in React 18:

> With Strict Mode starting in React 18, whenever a component mounts in development, React will simulate immediately unmounting and remounting the component.

I am getting the error highlighted above.

I am not entirely sure how to avoid this error, I have attempted to cleanup the hook. I have also tried checking if ads already exist (but this doesn't seem to want to work).

Any help would be much appreciated!